# Get button ID and use it as object property to reduce function repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to mix these three functions into one.

For that to work I need to get the button ID (thus removing it from the on function —what's the term for it?) and use it inside the function as a variable (previously declarated) and object property (also previously declarated).

```
const       time = {
                'name'  :   'time',
                'counter':  0,
                'in'    :   0,
                'val'   :   0
            },
            idea = {
                'name'  :   'idea',
                'counter':  0,
                'in'    :   0,
                'val'   :   0,
                'time'  :   1
            },
            story = {
                'name'  :   'story',
                'counter':  0,
                'in'    :   0,
                'val'   :   0,
                'time'  :   4,
                'req'   :   idea,
                'idea'  :   10
            },
            grana = {
                'name'  :   'grana',
                'counter':  0,
                'in'    :   0,
                'val'   :   0,
                'time'  :   1,
                'req'   :   story,
                'story' :   1
            }

// cooldowns
const       cooldown = {
                idea: 300,
                story: 2000,
                grana: 2000
            };

// adds to counter on click, checks buttons.
const addCounter = button => {
    button.counter += 1;
}


//Functions to be combined:
$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#idea', function(event) {
    let element = this;
    $('button').addClass('cooldown');
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('cooldown');
        addCounter(idea);
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        checkAll();
    }, cooldown.idea);
});
$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#story', function(event) {
    let element = this;
    $('button').addClass('cooldown');
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    removeCounter(story);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('cooldown');
        addCounter(story);
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        checkAll();
    }, cooldown.story);
});

$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#grana', function(event) {
        let element = this;
    $('button').addClass('cooldown');
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    removeCounter(grana);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('cooldown');
        addCounter(grana);
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        checkAll();
    }, cooldown.grana);
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do the three buttons have a common CSS class applied to them?

Comment: I don't understand what your `idea` and `cooldown.idea` variables are.  Perhaps you can edit your question to explain them.  I have the feeling that you don't need them, though.

Comment: @BobRodes Each item will have a different cooldown time, that's why cooldown.idea on one function and cooldown.story on another (and so on). I added it to the code, see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  See my answer below.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: var eleButton = $('#buttonDiv'); and then using this variable afterwards like eleButton.on(....), eleButton.attr(....) etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to your three buttons.  Also, dump your `cooldown` object, because you'll be adding that data as an attribute to each of your buttons.  For example:

```
<button id="idea" class="myClass" data-cooldown="300">MyButton</button>
```

Then, do this (use only one click handler, shared by all members of the class you added to the buttons):

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function(event) {
    let element = this;
    $('button').addClass('cooldown');
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('cooldown');
        addCounter(idea);
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        checkAll();
    }, event.toElement.dataset.cooldown);
});
```

The `dataset` property requires HTML5 and fairly late versions of browsers.  If your particular browser version doesn't support it, you can also do this instead (jQuery 1.4.1--I think--and later):

```
    }, $('#' + event.target.id).data('cooldown');
```

The essential technique is to apply a class to the buttons and use it for the event handler, and apply your value that is unique to each button as an attribute of the element in HTML.  There are a few varying ways to do that; I've given you two.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could take the click event logic to a seperate function and leave the event binding to be as it is. For an example,

```
$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#idea', function(event) {
    eventLogic(this)
});

$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#story', function(event) {
    eventLogic(this)
});

$('#buttonDiv').on('click', '#grana', function(event) {
    eventLogic(this)
});


function eventLogic(el){
    let element = el;
    let val; //This should be changed according to the clicked element
    $('button').addClass('cooldown');
    $(element).prop('disabled', true);

    if(event.currentTarget.id == '#idea'){
       val = cooldown.idea;
    }else if(event.currentTarget.id == '#story'){
       val = cooldown.story;
    }else if(event.currentTarget.id == '#grana'){
       val = cooldown.grana;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('cooldown');
        addCounter(idea);
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
        checkAll();
    },val)
}
```

Comment: But that way I'd need to add else ifs to every new button I introduce, right? That's not very effective, I think.